# Get resulted apk file path from android gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have gradle task that depends on assembleRelease

```
sendReleaseCandidate.dependsOn assembleRelease
```

And I want to get resulted apk file path. From my task I've wrote:

```
def apk = android.applicationVariants.release.outputFile
```

But it doesn't work. What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

ps: android plugin 0.11.1, for now I stick with `uri('./build/outputs/apk/<app_name>-release.apk').path` but it seems aweful.

Answer (score 7):

You can loop through the variants to find the one you need:

```
def apk = null
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if ( (variant.name).equals("release") ) {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            apk = output.outputFile
        }
    }
}
println "Found output file: " + apk
```